# JavaScript multiline string decode

Tags: javascript, string, decode

I have a string:

```
&lt;Grid&gt;&lt;Description&gt;LINE 1
LINE 2
LINE 3
LINE 4
&lt;/Description&gt;&lt;&lt;/Grid&gt;
```

I need it to be decoded with line breaks. I found solution:

```
function decodeString(stringToDecode) {
    if (!stringToDecode) {
        return stringToDecode;
    }
    return $('<div />').html(stringToDecode).text();
}
```

But it makes single line and replaces all the line breaks with spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use the following to replace your line breaks with `<br />` tags an then set the HTML:

```
return $('<div />').html(stringToDecode.replace(/\n/, '&lt;br /&gt;')).text();
```

Comment: I improved your solution: `var tempTagName = 'LineBreak'; var decodedString = $('<div />').html(stringToDecode.replace(/\n/g, '&lt;' + tempTagName + "/&gt;\r\n")).text(); return decodedString.replaceAll('<' + tempTagName + '/>', '\r\n');`

Comment: The line break Regexp should be `/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm`
http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/javascript-line-breaks.php

Answer (score 1):

```
function decodeString(stringToDecode) {
    return stringToDecode ? $('<div />').html(stringToDecode.replace(/[\n\r]/g, "<br> \r\n")).text() : ""
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your sample has CR/LF - but that is not a line break in HTML.  You need to replace it with a valid HTML line break ie the < br > tag.

Your function has a strange if statement that does not make much sense. Why return stringToDecode when you've just proven it is null?  Also, `$('<div />').html(stringToDecode).text()` will not do anything helpful.

Try something like this:

```
function decodeString(stringToDecode) {
if (!stringToDecode) {
    return "";
}
var regX = /\\n/g;
var replaceString = '<br> \\n';
return stringToDecode.replace(regX, replaceString);
}
```